# jQuery fadeInDiv() and Flexbox

Tags: jquery, css

When my `workitem` fadeing in, starting position is at the center and then it moves to the left when new one is showed. I want to spawn them as they should be, from the left to the right without any moving.

```js
$('.workitem').each(function(fadeInDiv){
  $(this).delay(fadeInDiv *1500).fadeIn(5000);
});
```

```css
#work {
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:flex-start;
  width:70%;
  height:70%;
  background-color:black;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="work">
  <div class="workitem"></div>
  <div class="workitem"></div>
  <div class="workitem"></div>
  <div class="workitem"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using fadeIn() sets the element's display, which is not what you're after.
you want to keep the item there (hidden) but just show it.

so you could consider using [fadeTo()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) to affect only the element's opacity
maybe something like:

```
$('.workitem').css("opacity","0").each(function(fadeInDiv){

 $(this).delay(fadeInDiv*1500).fadeTo("slow", 1);

});
```

bootply example: https://www.bootply.com/v9AtAQmDRR